# Option argument before callback argument

Tags: javascript, rest

I have an api endpoint called status. Which should be used like this:

```
status/ohio/columbus
status/nebraska/fremont
status/ohio/columbus/police
status/nebraska/fremont/fire
```

The state and city paths are mandatory but the department is not.

I'd like to have a function which updates a callback with the return value. Is the following function reasonable or confusing? Should I have multiple functions instead - getStatus and getStatusForDepartment?

```
function getStatus(state, city, department, callback) 
{
    let status = "status/"+state+"/"+city
    if(typeof department != "function"){
        status = status+"/"+ department
    }else{
        callback = department
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Seems fine, it's not uncommon with arguments that aren't required, it's usually solved the way you're doing it when those are arguments are in the middle of the list of arguments. Almost all libraries, including jQuery, does the same thing.

Comment: You also could just reorder it. Presumably `callback` is always required, so why not make it the first instead of the last argument? Another alternative is to pass a single argument which is an object with `state`, `city`, `callback` and maybe `department` properties). Or, presuming that you are doing an ajax call and callback is supposed to execute when it's done, just have your function return a promise and you can attach your callback to the returned promise instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is totally fine and a common pattern. Another option would be to have your function return a Promise, rather than relying on a callback. This would allow you to bypass checking if the last argument is a function or callback

```
function getStatus(state, city, department) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let status = "status/"+state+"/"+city
        if (department) {
            status += '/' + department;
        }
        ...

        if (successThingHappens) {
            resolve(data);
        } else {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
}

getStatus('CA', 'San Francisco').then((data) => {
    console.log('do something with', data);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error('something went wrong', error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the part regarding the "multiple functionss instead".
But about the requirement of having optional argument in the middle of the parameter list, I follow the object approach.

Instead of doing

```
getStatus(state, city, department, callback)
```

I do like this

```
var arg_list = {"state": state, "city": city, "department": department, "callback": callback};
getStatus(arg_list);
```

And within the function, assign the value from object to the varables.
This way you can omit and use any parameter.

This approach has one very good benefit. We often need to make changes to the parameter list. Sometime add new one where as sometime remove some from the parameter list and sometime we need to change the order etc. All these operations need to be done very carefully when using the parameters since this may make the function definition different to the function call. But with this approach such cases can be easily handled.